# Using social plugins for pre-existing Facebook posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

If there a way to use the Facebook Feed, Comments, and Like social plugins for existing Facebook posts?

We're looking for a way to have pages on our site supplementing existing Facebook posts made on our FB page. The goal is to keep all sharing, comments, and likes centralized around single post, rather than the usual model where each person shares a distinct post on their feed.

Example post from McDonalds: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151001277817014&set=a.10150319191897014.332821.50245567013&type=1

Ideally, we'd like to pull in the functionality of the above post (commenting, sharing, liking) on our page, meaning people can comment from our page and it is updated on the original post as well.

Entering variants of the Facebook post URL into the social plugins does not pull in the existing comments/likes/shares. It is treated like a separate piece of content instead.

Is this a policy issue, or is it just not technically possible at this time?

This is somewhat related to this previous question: [Social Plugins for Facebook Photos and Albums](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7961394/social-plugins-for-facebook-photos-and-albums)

Comment: I realise this is 6 months old, but I just found it as I think I posted a similar query last night. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593651/is-it-possible-to-use-facebooks-comments-plugin-with-graph-object-ids-graph-urls I have done exactly what are you were trying to do, but by making it myself. The question I posted is bascially the same that you already asked. Did you ever find a solution?